# Observer is not added

Tags: java

I'm currently working on an Java-Application, which checks every second the temperature of my computer. For the timing I made an `Timer` class which works with `Quartz` and for the checking of the temperature I made a class called `SysKeeper`. My problem is, that I want, that the `SysKeeper` is notified, when the `Timer` is triggered, but my `Observer` is not working, because the `Syskeeper` is not added as `Observer`.

Here you see my `Syskeeper` class:

```
public class SysKeeper implements Observer {
    private double temp;

    public void start() {
        Log.info("SysKeeper starting");
        Main.timer.addObserver(this);
    }

    private void checkTemp() {
        String buffer = CmdExecutor.execute("sudo vcgencmd measure_temp");
        String[] splitBuffer = buffer.split("=");
        String[] splitBuffer1 = splitBuffer[1].split("\'");
        temp = Double.parseDouble(splitBuffer1[0]);
        if (temp > 70.0) {
            //Main.not.sendMessage("Reached crit Temp: " + temp);
        }
        Log.info(temp + "");
    }

    public void kill() {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("HI");
        this.checkTemp();
    }
}
```

And this is my `Timer` class:

```
public class Timer extends Observable implements Job {

    public void start() {
        try {
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                    .newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("timer", "timer")
                    .withSchedule(
                            CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/1 * * * * ?"))
                    .build();

            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Timer.class)
                    .withIdentity("timer", "timer").build();

            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Timer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
        System.out.println("" + countObservers());//always 0
    }

    public void kill() {

    }
}
```

Here is also my `Main` class:

```
public class Main {

    public static final String spliterNetwork = ";";
    public static final String spliterParameter = "#";

    public static Timer timer;
    public static Server ser;
    public static SysKeeper kep;
    public static GPIO gpio;
    public static Log log;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        Main.init(args);
        Main.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
           public void run() {
                Main.stop();
            }
        }));
    }

    public static void init(String[] args) {
       timer = new Timer();
        log = new Log();
        ser = new Server();
        kep = new SysKeeper();
        gpio = new GPIO();
    }

    public static void start() throws UnknownHostException {
        Log.info("Welcome to iServer @ " + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        timer.start();
        log.start();
        ser.start();
        kep.start();
        gpio.start();
    }

    public static void stop() {
        Log.info("Programm shuts down");
        timer.kill();
        log.kill();
        ser.kill();
        kep.kill();
        gpio.kill();

        timer = null;
        log = null;
        ser = null;
        kep = null;
        gpio = null;
        Log.info("Good bye");
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `Main` class source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar wih Quartz, but it would seem that you have **two** distinct instances of `Timer`:

- The first `Timer` that is stored in `Main.timer`, created in `timer = new Timer()`, and having an observer added in `Main.timer.addObserver(this);` (in `SysKeeper`). This instance is never executed, that is, it never has its `execute()` method called.
- The second `Timer`, that is created by the first `Timer` in the line `JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Timer.class)...` this `Timer` is the one that is being executed (`scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);`) but it hasn't any `Observer` attached.

Comment: You might add this sentence to your answer: [`The JobDetail object is created by the Quartz client (your program) at the time the Job is added to the scheduler.`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02#TutorialLesson2-JobsAndTriggers) So it seems, you're right.